# how to use javascript in ie mode edge on address bar

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I typed JavaScript in the edge address bar and used it.
By the way, in ie mode, it was searching when I enter JavaScript in the address bar, so is there any other way to use it other than the edge developer tool?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested some bookmarklets in the Edge normal mode and in the IE mode.

Based on my test results, it looks like the bookmarklet works fine in the Edge normal mode.

The IE mode in the Edge browser does not support bookmarklets. This is the reason in IE mode it tries to search it.

At present, I did not found any workaround for this issue.

I would suggest you press the `ALT + SHIFT + I` key in the Edge browser and provide feedback to Microsoft regarding this issue.